# How to capture image metadata information in angular

Tags: angular, image, metadata

I want to fetch longitude, latitude and created date information while capturing image. I tried using "exif-js" package, but it is not working as expected.

I tried to get all tags on capturing image

```
import * as exif from 'exif-js';
public capturePicture(): void {
      const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
      let pictureData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      canvas.toBlob(async (blob: any) => {
        if (blob) {
          blob['lastModifiedDate'] = (new Date()).toISOString();
          // to set image name based on Source like Observation/Records Reveiw --> (Helper.getImageName(this.cameraRef.data.imageName || this.cameraRef.data.source)+ blob.size + '.jpg');
          blob['name'] = (Helper.getImageName(AppConstants.CAMERA_COMMON_IMAGE_NAME) + blob.size + '.jpg');
          blob['filename'] = blob['name'];
          this.cameraRef.data.Document_Original_Name = blob['name'];
          exif.getAllTags(blob);
          const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
        } 
      }, 'image/jpeg');

  }
```